# No Local Database on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2015, localdb

I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and when I tried to create a local database, there wasn't an option available.

[image]

Some people said I needed to download/install it separately but I already tried these 3 options:

1. I tried downloading and installing the separate LocalDB Installer to no avail.
   [image]
2. Updated Microsoft Visual Studio through Extension and Updates and it gave me an SSDTSetup file (Or same exe file can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501)
3. Some people suggested to go back to Microsoft Visual Studio 2015's installer and there's an option there to install it but I see no such option even after expanding all of the options.

I'm confused since last time I installed Microsoft Visual Studio there was an option like this (last year I think).

The local database looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnXYfOM1Dqw (at 1:58 of the video).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That template is no longer available, but using my free SQL Compact Toolbox extension you can easily add a SQL Server Compact database to your project and generate code to work with it on top. Microsoft's recommendation is to use SQL Server Express (Service-based database) instead.

Comment: I see, why did they remove it though? It's perfect for small apps. Still, thanks a lot.